# Css animations not applying to JSON list

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, json

I have a nice list of CSS generated cards. They contain icons and text and have a nice animation to expand once you tap on them, to reveal more icons and options. I hard coded the list and got it looking and behaving exactly the way I wanted.

Now, I have some JSON data on a database and I want to use that data to populate the list dynamically.

**Problem**: It works great, except the CSS animations no longer apply.

How can I fix this?  Here's my code.

**HTML**:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, minimal-ui">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/customFitStyling.css" type="text/css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/w3c_v4.css" type="text/css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/customFitFunctions.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>

    <!--APPEND CARDS-->
    <ul id="cardList" class="cards">

    </ul>
  </body>
</html>
```

**JavaScript**:

```
    // Sync with Firebase in real time.
    dbRef.on("value", snap =>
    {
      var workouts = snap.val();

      for (var i = 0, len = workouts.length; i < len; i++) // Populate list.
      {
        $("#cardList").append("<li><div class='card transform'>\n\
        <div class='cardInfo'><h3>" + workouts[i].title + "</h3><p>10 min.</p><a class='startIt' href='timer.html'>\n\
        <img src='images/playIcon.png' width='70' alt='' /></a><div class='infoIcons'>\n\
        <img src='images/thorso.png' width='48' alt='' /><img src='images/legs.png' width='28' alt='' />\n\
        <img src='images/cardio.png' width='48' alt='' /></div><div class='timeIcon'>\n\
        <img src='images/tenMinutes.png' width='66' alt='' /></div></div>\n\
        <div class='disappear'><div class='playIt'><a class='playButton' href='timer.html'>\n\
        <img src='images/playButtonUp.png' width='100' alt='' /><img src='images/playButtonDown.png' width='95' alt='' /></a>\n\
        </div><div class='deleteIt'><a class='deleteButton' href='#'>\n\
        <img src='images/thrashButtonUp.png' width='60' alt='' />\n\
        <img src='images/thrashButtonDown.png' width='55' alt='' /></a></div><div class='modifyIt'>\n\
        <a class='modifyButton' href='#'><img src='images/cogButtonUp.png' width='100' alt=''/>\n\
        <img src='images/cogButtonDown.png' width='95' alt='' /></a></div></div></div></li>");
      }
    });
```

jQuery:

```
  // Triggers CSS animation for cards.
  $(".card").click(function()
  {
    $(this).toggleClass("transformActive");
    $(".disappear", this).toggleClass("appear");
  });
```

CSS:

```
/**
* ROUTINE CARDS SECTION
*
*/
/* Style cards and content */
.cards
{
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  top: 60px;
  list-style: none;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
  z-index: -1;
}

.cards li
{
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}

.card
{
  position: relative;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  height: 150px;
  width: 100%;
  left: -6%;
  border-radius: 8px;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px #686868;
}

.transform
{
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 0.2s ease;
  -o-transition: all 0.2s ease;
  -ms-transition: all 0.2s ease;
  transition: all 0.2s ease;
}

.transformActive
{
  background-color: #ffffff;
  height: 260px;
  width: 100%;
  box-shadow: 6px 6px 6px #888888;
}

/* CARD CONTENT SECTION */
.cardInfo
{
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
  width: 95%;
  height: 130px;
  text-align: left;
}

.cardInfo h3
{
  position: relative;
  top: 5px;
}

.cardInfo p
{
  position: relative;
  color: black;
  text-align: right;
  top: -40px;
}

.startIt
{
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0px;
}

.timeIcon
{
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0px;
  left: 78%;
}

.infoIcons
{
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
  top: -20px;
  width: 52%;
  height: 100px;
}

.infoIcons img
{
  margin-left: 6px;
}

#holder
{
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 80px;
}

/* CARD ANIMATION */
.disappear
{
  position: relative;
  width: 95%;
  height: 40%;
  top: 8%;
  margin: auto;
  opacity: 0;
}

.appear
{
  -webkit-animation: appearFade 1.2s ease forwards;
  -moz-animation: appearFade 1.2s ease forwards;
  -o-animation: appearFade 1.2s ease forwards;
  -ms-animation: appearFade 1.2s ease forwards;
  animation: appearFade 1.2s ease forwards;
}

@keyframes appearFade
{
  0%
  {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100%
  {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

/* CARD OPTIONS ICONS */
.playIt
{
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
}

.playButton img:last-child
{
  display: none;
}

.playButton:hover img:first-child
{
  display: none;
}

.playButton:hover img:last-child
{
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  left: 3px;
  top: 3px;
}

.deleteIt
{
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
  top: 25px;
}

.deleteButton img:last-child
{
  display: none;
}

.deleteButton:hover img:first-child
{
  display: none;
}

.deleteButton:hover img:last-child
{
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  left: 2px;
  top: 2px;
}

.modifyIt
{
  position: absolute;
  right: 0px;
  top: 0px;
}

.modifyButton img:last-child
{
  display: none;
}

.modifyButton:hover img:first-child
{
  display: none;
}

.modifyButton:hover img:last-child
{
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  left: 0px;
  top: 3px;
}
```

Comment: Please include the relevant CSS, thanks

Comment: show us the html of a hard coded, properly working card (which results in “what it should look like”)

Comment: `<li><div class='card transform'></div>` You're closing the main card div right away, therefore all the following elements get pushed underneath it...

Comment: I just indented all your appended html and you seem to have two extra closing divs at the end (before the final `</li>`)  So IMO your html is mucked up.

Comment: Added HTML for hardcode, reviewing your suggestions regarding closing tag.

Comment: Removing closing tag worked to get styling correct, but animations are still not firing.

Answer (score 2):

Check if removing the `</div>` close tag in the `<div class="card transform">` works well. I don't know, how are you using your css classes but looks like that the childs elements are outside the parent div container.